# Why is Pipenv not using the correct version of Python when installing packages?

Tags: python, pipenv

I have read various other similar questions without finding one that matches my issue. Feel free to redirect me if I have missed one.

I have Python 3.10.7 installed on my system (Arch Linux) and I need to work on an older project that uses Python 3.6.9.
I know this project works with 3.6.9 and its dependencies are correctly installed because I can see it running fine in a docker container that I have entered to check the version of Python.

As I have tried that several times I make sure to start again with a fresh environment with:

`pipenv --rm`
`rm Pipfile`

Then I do:

`pipenv --python 3.6.9`

Python 3.6.9 is installed with Pyenv successfully and so is the virtual environment.

If I  do `pipenv shell` then `python --version` is `Python 3.6.9` as expected. Then I `Ctrl-D` to get out of the environment.

I then do `pipenv install -r requirements.txt` and that crashes with the following traceback:

```
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile...
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 867, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 844, in main
        from pipenv.vendor.vistir.misc import replace_with_text_stream
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
        from .cli import cli
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .command import cli  # noqa
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 7, in <module>
        from pipenv.cli.options import (
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pipenv.project import Project
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 2
        from __future__ import annotations
        ^
    SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, I understand that the installation is using Python 3.10 here while the code is expected to be run with 3.6 where annotations is in future.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `annotations` wasn't added until Python 3.7. It's simply not available in Python 3.6 (which is no longer supported; you should really upgrade to a newer version of Python. Even 3.7 is going out of support next summer, though that could be affected by the delay in releasing Python 3.11).

Comment: I definitely agree about upgrading, actually that's the first thing I need to do on this project. But I would like to be able to install it first. Indeed thanks for reminding me about the 3.7 introduction of annotations, but wasn't it present in 3.6 through __future__? I'm at a loss since this project runs on Python 3.6 in its docker container.

Comment: No. `__future__` doesn't affect *past* versions of Python. It only introduces new *optional* (and opt-in) features that will be made *mandatory* (i.e., you can't opt out) in the future. (Though in the case of `annotations`, it's not clear when/if it will become mandatory at this time.)

Comment: That is, when a new `__future__` feature is introduce, it's not backported to all previous versions of Python. It doesn't "magically" pull features from a future, unrelated version of Python; it just provides a way to optionally use now a feature that will be made mandatory later.

Comment: great explanation. So if I understand you correctly, that error should also appear on the original project since it runs 3.6.9 and it does not have `annotations`. The fact that it's not the case then indicates that the error is probably not related to the virtual environment to start with.

Comment: What's particularly odd is that if it is running 3.10, as it appears, then it should be able to import `annotations`.

Comment: It might be that, somehow, you are running Python 3.6 (which pipenv uses in the last command), but your PYTHONPATH points to /usr/lib/python3.10. Run a `env | grep -i python` to see what environment variables are still set.

Comment: Also try and run `python --version`, `which pipenv`, `which python`, and `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version, sys.path)"`.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [the Python 3.10.7 VS 3.6.9 comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html), as it might help you find a solution.

Comment: Can you post output of `which python`?

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.6 support was dropped by pipenv on `2022.4.20`. Please check the pipenv version on your docker container if you're using an older version of pipenv in it.

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you use the respective piping version for `python 3.6` and add that in your requirements.txt file.

`pipenv==2018.11.26`

You can refer to this [doc](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/changelog/#id526) and also [this](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#installation)

Answer (score 1):

you can make sure you have specifiled the correct python ver in your pip file with:

```
pipenv --py
```

it should show path to the correct python  executable
and if you still having problem try to del your pip.lock and reinstalling the package you can do this by :
`pipenv lock --clear` following by `pipenv install`